# Adding Mailchimp newsletter popup to existing Wordpress theme

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, mailchimp, newsletter

I have a Wordpress site with the theme "Adventurous".

I want to incorporate a Mailchimp newsletter signup popup on my Home page.

Apparently, I need to add this code to my html code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//s3.amazonaws.com/downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-forms/popup/embed.js" data-dojo-config="usePlainJson: true, isDebug: false"></script><script type="text/javascript">require(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function(L) { L.start({"baseUrl":"mc.us10.list-manage.com","uuid":"58956881c4c2157fb0e1c0859","lid":"00cc0645d7"}) })</script>
```

However, I don't know where to actually put this code, since the theme is put together with the help of lots of php files, instead of the basic html style I'm used to.

What I've done so far to build my site is mainly to add pages and work with that from the Wordpress interface.

Any tips?

Comment: You can use mailchimp API using mailchimp API parser class to make a custom plugin which can do this thing...

Comment: hmm.. can't say i understand much of that.. could you give me some pointers?